# how to know if a MFC application is open when it is going to be uninstalled

Tags: mfc, uninstallation

I have a MFC application in which I want to implement a part, which displays a message popup when user is going to uninstall it while keeping the application open. But I am not getting any clue regarding this. Can anyone please suggest a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a semaphore with a unique name. Then in your uninstallation program you check if the semaphore exists, if yes that means that the application is running.

In your program:

```
CreateSemaphore(NULL, 0, 1, "Some unique string of your choice") ;
```

In your uninstall program:

```
  BOOL isrunning = FALSE ;
  HANDLE hsem = CreateSemaphore(NULL, 0, 1, "Some unique string of your choice") ;

  if (hsem != NULL)
  {
    if (GetLastError() == ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS)
      isrunning = TRUE ;

    CloseHandle(hsem) ;
  }
```